# Linux, combine images to precise scaled tiled pdf. Imagemagick? Alternative?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-gallery

I have a large collection of jpeg images with the same aspect ratio but not necessarily the same resolution. I need to combine those into one (or multiple) pdf documents with multiple images showing up per page.
I need to specify a target page size (a4/letter) and I need precise control over the final size of the combined images.

The scenario is something like "combining a list of passport photos for print".

I tried montage from Imagemagick but I cannot get the scaling done. If all images had exactly the same resolution I could try to find some voodoo numbers and make it work somehow.
Maybe imagemagick is the wrong approach? Is there a way to create a pdf template with x:y "slots" that already have the correct size for print and then "feed" the images into those slots?

Comment: Maybe if you provided 2-3 images of different resolutions and a template with slots, somebody might help out...

Comment: I was asking if it would be a better approach and how to create such a template. As an alternative to fiddling around with montage and convert. So obviously I do not know how to do that. (At least not on linux cmd. I'd like to avoid writing an app for such a simple feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done thing kind of thing with `pdflatex`. You write a tiny script in Python/Ruby/bash/whatever to walk your directory finding all the image files, then for each set of N, output LaTeX source code laying out the N images on a page. Finally, pipe that into `pdflatex` and you'll have a nice PDF document with all your images embedded. It should be less than 10 lines of code, plus a little boilerplate.

That would paste the images at their original resolution and rely on the PDF renderer to size them to the paper. If some of the source images are very large, it could be a bit wasteful. I suppose you could use IM or equivalent to size the larger ones down a bit first.

**Edit:** I made a tiny example. My latex is awful, I'm sure you could write something much better:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts <<HEADER
\\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\\usepackage{relsize}
\\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\\begin{document}
HEADER

ARGV.each_slice(4).to_a.each do |images|
    puts "\\begin{center}"
    puts "\\thispagestyle{empty}"
    images.each {|filename| puts "\\includegraphics[width=2in]{#{filename}}"}
    puts "\\end{center}"
    puts "\\newpage"
end

puts <<FOOTER
\\end{document}
FOOTER
```

Run with something like:

```
./layout.rb x/* > x.tex
```

To scan the directory `x/` for jpg files and generate a latex file with images set out four up, then:

```
pdflatex x.tex
evice x.pdf
```

To generate the PDF and view it.

Comment: That is a nice idea. I wrote so many papers and theses in latex but I just didn't think about that. This would give much more control and allow non-grid layouts as well. Instead of creating new source for each page, I could create a template with fixed filenames and just run a script to copy and rename the images.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, because I use a latex as solution now. As a note: I do not create tex code from a script. I build the .tex template in sth like Texmaker and then use a script to switch out the images on disk or in the template. That way more complicated layouts are manageable and the templates are easier to control/share. Even quick and dirty switching images by hand is possible. For a mixed solution one can run the .tex file through sed and replace e.g. captions for dynamic parts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a somewhat acceptable way with montage

```
montage -geometry +0+0 ../*.jpg +compress -resize 198x280 -extent 198x280 -tile 3x3 -gravity center -page a4 test.pdf
```

Starting with a4 point size 595x842 the target size for the tiles can be calculated as a percentage. In the example its 1/3 of the page and a 3x3 grid. 
-extent makes sure that a slightly smaller image will be scaled to the desired size. This way the grid stays intact and prints can be cut easier. 
It would be good enough for cutting out student id cards etc. But it is not as precise as one might want it for good prints. I will look into the latex approach and see how that works out.

Comment: Very useful suggestion, worked like a charm! Thanks